# How do add a field to a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have the following model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

How can I add a field to it?

Comment: Assuming this is Ruby On Rails, you should use migrations : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17728201/adding-updating-column-in-a-model-using-rubymine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the type of the field you wish to add? If it is a string do it like below:

```
rails generate migration add_field_to_products field:string
```

Where 'field' is the name of the field you want to add, so rename accordingly.

Then do in the command line `rake db:migrate` and after that the field should be in the model.

Also, this question is a duplicate of: [Adding a column to an existing table in a Rails migration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834809/adding-a-column-to-an-existing-table-in-a-rails-migration) . There is more discussion of this there if it's still unclear.

Comment: Shouldn't I write anything on the file directly? Or is this the only way, through the command line?

Comment: Well you have the model already, so I assume you already ran the original migration which created the products table. But if you haven't yet ran it yet, then you could just add t.string :field inside the create_table loop. Otherwise yes this is the correct way, this is so your schema will change to reflect the new field.

Comment: Can't I just add a field to the products table inside the products migration?

Answer (score 0):

You should generate a separate migration with `rails g migration [name]`, where you declare your column:

```
add_column :products, :[column_name], :[datatype]
```

Where `[column_name]` is the name of the column you want to add and `[datatype]` stands for it's datatype: string, integer and etc.
After that you should run migration with `rake db:migrate` to add new column to your table.